# Bluedevil wizard starts on KDE startup

Tags: linux, bluetooth, kde, gentoo

Bluedevil wizard (3 copies) starts on each boot after KDE start. There are no bluetooth devices near PC or smth. Why and how to fix?

[image]

Comment: Check in the `System Settings` -> `Startup and shutdown` -> `Service Manager` -> `Startup services`. If it is there -> disable it and it wont start again at login time automatically.

Comment: It doesn't help.